# How to remove all characters after a given character in a column dataframe with Python

Tags: string, python-3.x, dataframe, replace

example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'state': ['Auckland', 'Otago (....)','Wellington','Dunedin','Hamilton'],'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2001,2002],'pop': [1.5, 1.7,3.6, 2.4, 2.9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to remove all that occur after the string **'('** in the state column.

Many thanks for your help.

Samir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about pandas, but with a little search in google, here is a code that can handle your situation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'state': ['Auckland', 'Otago (....)','Wellington','Dunedin','Hamilton'],'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2001,2002],'pop': [1.5, 1.7,3.6, 2.4, 2.9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

for state in df.state:
    if "(" in state:
        row_num = df.loc[df['state']==state].index[0]
        df.at[row_num, 'state'] = state[:state.index("(")]

print(df.state)
```

Here is the output:

```
0      Auckland
1        Otago
2    Wellington
3       Dunedin
4      Hamilton
Name: state, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) function goes over all of the values in a `Series` and returns another `Series` containing the results of some function. From there you can use the [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method in a slice.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'state': ['Auckland', 'Otago (....)','Wellington','Dunedin','Hamilton'],'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2001,2002],'pop': [1.5, 1.7,3.6, 2.4, 2.9]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['state'] = df.state.map(lambda x: x[0: x.find('(') - 1] if '(' in x else x)

print(df)
```

Yields:

```
   pop       state  year
0  1.5    Auckland  2000
1  1.7       Otago  2001
2  3.6  Wellington  2002
3  2.4     Dunedin  2001
4  2.9    Hamilton  2002
```